# Java (MQ). Не запускается imqbrokerd

Tags: java, glassfish

Для посыла сообщений мне требуется открыть брокер на Glassfish. Однако при открытии выводится следующее окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете подсказать, как исправить данную ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

Здесь обсуждалась эта ошибка:

1. [ERROR [B3276]: Starting a GlassFish-managed broker directly using imqbrokerd is not allowed](http://download.oracle.com/javaee-archive/glassfish.java.net/users/2012/01/57409.html)
2. [ERROR [B3276]: Starting a GlassFish-managed broker directly using imqbrokerd is not allowed](http://www.databaseusers.com/article/6154125/ERROR+%5BB3276%5D%3A+Starting+a+GlassFish-managed+broker+directly+using+imqbrokerd+is+not+allowed)

П.С.
Не по теме, но вдруг поможет. Если надо только для тестирования на своем компьютере, то очень просто и быстро запускается `apache activemq`. Рекомендую (сорри, если коммент не по теме).